# spring hbaseTemplate throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a host:port pair: PBUF

Tags: hbase, spring-data, spring-data-hadoop

I am a newbie for Hbase and I want to continue to use spring solution, hBaseTemplate to access HBase. But I tested a lot of times and can never be successful in doing so. This is what I did.
The sample I am using is: 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-book/tree/master/hadoop/hbase

I am using latest stable HBase build, version 1.0.1.1
When I start UserApp, I got this error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userUtils' defined in file [/Users/fhe/spring/spring-data-book/hadoop/hbase/target/classes/com/oreilly/springdata/hadoop/hbase/UserUtils.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a host:port pair: PBUF

192.168.1.75��ݠ���)��}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:158)
    at com.oreilly.springdata.hadoop.hbase.UserApp.main(UserApp.java:30)
```

So I google this error:  Not a host:port pair: PBUF

checking the POM file,

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.hadoop.version>1.0.0.RELEASE</spring.hadoop.version>
        <hadoop.version>1.0.1</hadoop.version>
        <hbase.version>0.92.1</hbase.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    </properties>
```

People said it is because version is different from client and server. so I donwload hbaseServer 0.92.1, start HBaseServer and then start project again, now error is:

```
09:22:32.259 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session 0x14e5f064fea0003 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:599) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:286) ~[zookeeper-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3-1240972]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1035) ~[zookeeper-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3-1240972]
09:22:32.503 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server /127.0.0.1:2181
09:22:32.504 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] WARN  o.a.z.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient - SecurityException: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration occurred when trying to find JAAS configuration.
09:22:32.504 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO  o.a.z.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient - Client will not SASL-authenticate because the default JAAS configuration section 'Client' could not be found. If you are not using SASL, you may ignore this. On the other hand, if you expected SASL to work, please fix your JAAS configuration.
09:22:32.505 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session 0x14e5f064fea0002 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
```

Even if I am using Hbase Shell, it is throwing a lot exceptions, so I gave up old version of hBase server.

I tried to use same hBaseClient in the POM to match latest HBase Server, 1.0.1.1, but it is either jar not available error, or some other major minor version exceptions.

Can anyone who has such experiences tell me how you fixed it and use hbaseTemplate to work with latest stable hBaseBuild? How do you config the spring project etc? Can you show me your working solution?

Thanks very much.

Connection String:
This is the context that it is being used in the sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:hdp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="hbase.properties"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.oreilly.springdata.hadoop.hbase"/>

    <hdp:configuration id="hadoopConfiguration">
      fs.default.name=hdfs://localhost:9000
    </hdp:configuration>

    <hdp:hbase-configuration configuration-ref="hadoopConfiguration" zk-quorum="${hbase.host}" zk-port="${hbase.port}"/>

    <bean id="hbaseTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseTemplate">
        <property name="configuration" ref="hbaseConfiguration"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I tried to change hadoop dependence to:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Now the PBUF error is gone, instead, I am having this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/spring/application-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.hadoop.config.HadoopNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/data/hadoop/config/HadoopNamespaceHandler : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:158)
```

Comment: Post the connection string in your spring context file.  It looks like you just have a bad database connection string.

Comment: @RobertMoskal, above is the context xml. Is there anything suspecious here?

Answer (score 1):

I saw your comment on GitHub so I added the HBase sample app from the Spring Data book to the Spring for Apache Hadoop samples repo here - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop-samples/tree/master/hbase

At the same time I updated the versions to more recent versions for the following:

```
spring.hadoop.version: 2.2.0.RELEASE
hadoop.version: 2.6.0
hbase.version: 0.98.5-hadoop2
```

I'll give this a try with the latest stable HBase release (1.0.1.1) later on. We use 0.98.5-hadoop2 when we build the Spring for Apache Hadoop project.

Comment: I tried the above example, its throwing like HADOOP_HOME dir is not set, where do i set the HADOOP_HOME dir in this application?